# Robotframework - appium testing for hybrid android app (Angular)

Tags: xpath, appium, robotframework

I have a hard time testing our hybrid app with Robotframework tests using appium library. The application has 2 contexts:

1. Native (android)
2. Web (Angular)

The problem that I Have is when I'm in the web context and I'm trying to use XPath locators to locate elements that contain some text using the expression: `Click Element    //*[contains(@text,some_containing_text)]` I would have the result of the root element which contains the element that I'm trying to locate. So in the end my test is clicking all the wrong way then it should be clicking because of that locator returning the root element of the HTML page.

This functionality of locating elements by just saying "Click element that contains something like this" is working with the selenium library on our Web application. But my question is why (or what I'm doing wrong) it doesn't work with appium Robotframework library.

Using appium 1.6.3.

I'm searching for span with the text `Ukončit`

```
<app-attendance-detail class="ng-star-inserted">
<div class="py-4">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="mb-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12"><h4 class="fs-14 mb-1 font-weight-bold">úterý, 09:56:00 26.07.2022</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="fs-14 fs-md-16 mb-4 font-weight-bold text-gray-light ng-star-inserted">
                        <span>Začátek dnešní směny od</span> dnes v 9:45 </h4>
                    <div class="e-timer text-gray ng-star-inserted">00:10h</div>
                    <a href="#" title="#" preventdefault=""
                       class="btn btn-primary w-100 text-uppercase font-weight-bold px-9 mt-6 ng-star-inserted"><i
                        class="icon icon-stop position-relative bottom-1 mr-1"></i><span translate=""
                                                                                         ng-reflect-translate="">Ukončit</span></a>
                    <div class="row row-xs mt-2 ng-star-inserted">
                        <div class="col-6 px-1"><a href="#" title="#" preventdefault=""
                                                   class="btn btn-white border-primary-dark text-primary w-100 text-uppercase font-weight-bold px-9"><i
                            class="icon icon-pause position-relative bottom-1 mr-1"></i><span>Začátek<br>přestávky</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 px-1"><a href="#" title="#" preventdefault=""
                                                   class="btn btn-white border-primary-dark text-primary w-100 text-uppercase font-weight-bold px-9"><span>Odchod<br>jiné</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-4"><h4 translate="" class="fs-14 fs-md-16 mb-2 font-weight-bold"
                                      ng-reflect-translate="">Docházka</h4><a title="#" target="_blank"
                                                                              class="d-block bg-white px-3 border-radius-sm box-shadow-sm mb-2 text-gray ng-star-inserted"
                                                                              href="https://h5tws.cezdata.corp:44320/sap/bc/bsp/sap/zjd_dovol/overview.htm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col py-3 pb-3">
                            <div translate="" class="fs-16 font-weight-bold text-uppercase" ng-reflect-translate="">
                                Žádost o dovolenou
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div
                            class="col col-xs py-2 text-center border-left border-gray-light d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                            <div class="text-gray"><i class="icon icon-forward"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a><a title="#" target="_blank"
                       class="d-block bg-white px-3 border-radius-sm box-shadow-sm mb-2 text-gray ng-star-inserted"
                       href="https://h5tws.cezdata.corp:44320/sap/bc/bsp/sap/zjd_doli/selection_screen.htm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col py-3 pb-3">
                            <div translate="" class="fs-16 font-weight-bold text-uppercase" ng-reflect-translate="">
                                Docházkový list
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div
                            class="col col-xs py-2 text-center border-left border-gray-light d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                            <div class="text-gray"><i class="icon icon-forward"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a></div>
                <div class="mt-4"><h4 translate="" class="fs-14 fs-md-16 mb-2 font-weight-bold"
                                      ng-reflect-translate="">Záznamy</h4><a routinglink="attendance/records"
                                                                             href="#" title="#"
                                                                             class="d-block bg-white px-3 border-radius-sm box-shadow-sm mb-2 text-gray"
                                                                             ng-reflect-routing-link="attendance/records">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col py-3 pb-3">
                            <div translate="" class="fs-16 font-weight-bold text-uppercase" ng-reflect-translate="">
                                Přehled záznamů
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div
                            class="col col-xs py-2 text-center border-left border-gray-light d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                            <div class="text-gray"><i class="icon icon-forward"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <app-modal-dialog styleclass="shadow" ng-reflect-style-class="shadow" ng-reflect-show-header="false"
                      ng-reflect-dismissable-mask="false" ng-reflect-dialog-id="4">
        <p-dialog class="p-element ng-tns-c30-7 ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-style-class="shadow"
                  ng-reflect-visible="false" ng-reflect-modal="true" ng-reflect-dismissable-mask="false"
                  ng-reflect-transition-options="0ms" ng-reflect-show-header="false" ng-reflect-draggable="true"
                  ng-reflect-resizable="true" ng-reflect-close-on-escape="true" ng-reflect-base-z-index="1050">
        </p-dialog>
    </app-modal-dialog>
    <app-modal-dialog styleclass="shadow" ng-reflect-style-class="shadow" ng-reflect-show-header="false"
                      ng-reflect-dialog-id="5" ng-reflect-dismissable-mask="false">
        <p-dialog class="p-element ng-tns-c30-8 ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-style-class="shadow"
                  ng-reflect-visible="false" ng-reflect-modal="true" ng-reflect-dismissable-mask="false"
                  ng-reflect-transition-options="0ms" ng-reflect-show-header="false" ng-reflect-draggable="true"
                  ng-reflect-resizable="true" ng-reflect-close-on-escape="true" ng-reflect-base-z-index="1050">
        </p-dialog>
    </app-modal-dialog>
</div>
```

This is the keyword in Robot testcase

```
Attendance_action
[Arguments]        ${action}
Click element      //*[contains(@text, "${action}")]
Sleep              2s
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block showing an example of the HTML you are trying to process with your XPath expression.

Comment: Also, you need to clarify what your XPath expression actually is. NB the expression `//*[contains(@text,some_containing_text)]` returns every element for which the string value of it's attribute named `text` contains the string value of its child element named `some_containing_text`. If you had no element named `some_containing_text` in the document, then that second string value would evaluate to a zero-length string every time, and I'd expect the expression to match every element in the document, because `contains($x, "")` is true, no matter what `$x` is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited the question and added part of HTML block in which I'm searching with the exact word that I'm looking for

Comment: Can you please include the source code in which you make your query? At the very least the lines of code in which you deal with Appium's XPath API and pass it the XPath expression? At the moment your question includes the example `Click Element    //*[contains(@text,some_containing_text)]` but that's clearly not an XPath expression and it's not a Python expression either.

Comment: It is not a python code. I'm using a robotframework which has own syntax. This is the link to the appium lib docs  https://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html
And the added keyword I provided in the above I'm just calling in the testcase. So I'm sure that I'm on current page and the keyword should click the element with the provided text and wait 2 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for updating the question to include the details of how the XPath is called. It seems to me that you will end up with an expression like `//*[contains(@text, "Ukončit")]`; I would not expect that to return anything because the expression `@text` is a refererence to an attribute with the name `text`. It's not a reference to the textual content of an element.

I suspect what you actually meant to enter was an expression like this:

`//*[text()[contains(., "Ukončit")]]`

Translation: any element which contains a text node which itself contains the string "Ukončit". That should return a single `span` element:

```html
<span translate="" ng-reflect-translate="">Ukončit</span>
```